# Writing a file in array in C++

Tags: c++, file, file-io

When i run my program it just asks for the size and terminates. Is there anything wrong with the logic?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Enter size of array\n";
int x;
cin >> x;
int a [x];
ifstream data ("numbers.txt");

if(data.is_open()){
    cout << "Enter the elements\n";
    for(int i = 0 ; i<x ; i++){
        data >> a[i];
    }
for(int j = 0 ; j<x ; j++){
    cout << a[j];
}

}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by terminates? Do you get the command prompt back immediately afterwards?

Comment: 1) Variable length arrays are a compiler extension (consider using `std::vector`), 2) you seem to want to save the numbers in the file but you used an `ifstream`

Comment: No. Impossible. because you don't the size of array in compile time.

Comment: Your title says you are writing to a file, but I only see reading from a file.  Which is it, reading or writing?  By the way, reading uses `ifstream` and writing uses `ofstream`.  Note the difference in the first letter, 'i' for input and 'o' for output.

Comment: I suggest placing a breakpoint at the end of `main`.  When running the debugger, this should stop the IDE from closing the console window.

Answer (score -1):

You can not create static array like you are trying to do:

```
int a [x];
```

Instead you need to dynamically allocate memory:

```
int *a = new int[x];
```

And properly release it before exit:

```
delete [] a;
```

Comment: Recommending a `std::vector<int>` would probably be the better choice.

Comment: If that was the problem, the program would not compile, but it does (because it's using a compiler extension).